# Navigating cross-references in Word 2010 inserts diamond shape

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, cross-reference

I am having an issue with Microsoft Word and navigating cross references.
I have inserted a cross reference to a chapter header and it works. When I use the alt+left arrow combination, this takes me back to the cross reference as expected. However,  it also replaces one the characters in the cross reference with a diamond shape, depending on where the cursor is.

Checking online I find that alt+left arrow is used for going 'back' and also for inserting the diamond shape. Is there a way to stop Word inserting this shape every time I navigate from cross references?

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Is the diamond shape inserted or is a character replaced by a diamond shape?

Comment: The diamond shape replaces a character within the cross reference (which character depends on cursor location)